# RMarkdown - impossible to knit

Tags: package, r-markdown, install.packages

I am using RStudio Version 1.3.1093 and R 3.5.1 GUI 1.70 El Capitan build (7543). When I try to knit in RMarkdown I get the following error message:
"Rendering markdown documents requires updated versions of the following packages: knitr, rmarkdown, tinytex. Do you want to install these packages now?"

I clicked yes, but then if I click 'knit' I get the same error message.

I then tried to install.packages manually but I still get the same error message.

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Have you ran `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`? I also like to add `dep = TRUE` as an argument in my `install.packages()` to add extra needed dependencies.

Comment: It also might be worth creating a new project and pasting the code in a brand new RStudio session

Comment: I’m confident updating R and RStudio will help. (:

Comment: Indeed M.A. - I updated R, since RStudio was already running on the lastest version, and it fixed the issue. Thanks both for your comments!